# Multivariable weird function

Tags: real-analysis, integration, multivariable-calculus

I have to prove two statements, but this function is so weird( and hard to work with )...I just can't figure out how to solve this.

The given function is $\varphi:\mathbb{R}^N\rightarrow\mathbb{R} $ such that $$\varphi(x) = \left\{ \begin{array}{ll}
0, & \textrm{if $\lVert x\lVert\geq1$}\\
e^{-(1-\|x\|^2)^{-1}}, & \textrm{if $\lVert x\lVert<1$}
\end{array} \right. $$

Considering $x\in\mathbb{R}^N$ and $\lVert x\lVert^2=x_1^2+\ldots+x_N^2$.

My task is to show that $\varphi$ is $C^\infty$ and that $$\int_{\mathbb{R}^N}\varphi(nx) dx=\frac{1}{n^N}\int_{\mathbb{R}^N}\varphi(x) dx.$$

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Wait, isn't the latter true for any integrable function?

Comment: Yeah, it's just a change of variables I think. Take $x' = nx$.

Comment: This kind of functions are called mollifiers: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mollifier. Note the definition in the article, that's why you need the second property. To prove what you need to prove you need to prove the continuity of the first derivative, and then reduce the problem for higher order derivatives to that one.

Comment: Im looking at your link right now.

Comment: To prove it is $C^1$ should I write $\varphi(x+v)=\varphi(x)+\nabla\varphi(x)\cdot v+r(v)$ and show that $\lim_{v\rightarrow 0}r(v)/\lVert v\lVert =0$ ?

Comment: I could do that, but like I said at the beginning, this function is weird(and ugly), looks like this simple way gives me a lot of work. Im looking for a clever way.

Comment: Work first in one variable with $$f(x) = \begin{cases} e^{-1/x^2}, & x>0 \\ 0, & x\le 0\end{cases}.$$ To prove smoothness, it is helpful to find (inductively) the general form of its $n$th derivative.

Comment: I agree with Ted Shifrin that you should first prove smoothness of his suggested function $f$. Your $\varphi$ can be obtained by composing $f$ with quite tame functions. But, if I remember correctly, the induction he suggests will be easier if you don't try to evaluate the $n$th derivative completely but just prove that it equals (at positive arguments) $f$ times a polynomial in $1/x$.

Comment: Working on that, probably tomorrow I'm gonna have something to show here. Thank you very much.

Comment: @Integral Well as pointed out earlier, these functions are called mollifiers and are extensively used in different areas of analysis, and on the contrary, they are one of the most beautiful and well behaved functions you encounter. So they maybe weird but serious issues if you call them ugly.... :) :P